# How to log login attempts with machine name

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Is there a way to log login attempts in SQL Server, including machine name together with the machine IP address?

I read something about login triggers, but I don't know if it's useful for my needs.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: both 2008 r2 and 2012

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Login auditing -- In SQL Server Management Studio, open SQL Server Properties > Security > Login Auditing.

There are four options available:

1. **None** - Neither successful nor failed logins will be audited.
2. **Failed logins only** - Failed logins will be audited, but successful
   logins will be ignored.
3. **Successful logins only** - Successful logins will be audited, but
   failed logins will be ignored.
4. **Both failed and successful login**s - Login will be audited regardless
   of success and failure

Once you click OK, settings will save and take effect after the restart of the service.

Once you've turned on auditing, the next step is to be able to find the results of auditing required. You can find this recorded in the SQL Server log.

On how to read the sql server log you can refer [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/)..

In SQL server 2012 you can use SQL Server Extended Events to capture failed logins -

To set up Auditing using extended events and SQL server Audit you can read [Using Extended Events to review SQL Server failed logins
-](http://www.sqlshack.com/using-extended-events-review-sql-server-failed-logins/) -

Comment: yes, this works fine, but I need also machine name because I want to know if the login has been made from a domain pc or from an external one, while this system logs only the ip address. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes its possible, If you have log management software, another good place to look is the Application event log for the operating system. You can view this by using the Computer Management tool. If you expand System Tools and then Event Viewer, you'll see the Application event log wher you can see the details like success or failure Audit. open its properties and you can see source and user for further details

Comment: unfortunately the OS registers the server name even for remote logons, I'll try to figure out if this behavior can be changed